# Google codejam APAC Test practice round: Parentheses Order

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I spent one day solving [this problem](https://code.google.com/codejam/contest/4214486/dashboard#s=p3) and couldn't find a solution to pass the large dataset.

Problem

An n parentheses sequence consists of n "("s and n ")"s.

Now, we have all valid n parentheses sequences. Find the k-th smallest sequence in **lexicographical** order.

For example, here are all valid 3 parentheses sequences in lexicographical order:

```
((()))

(()())

(())()

()(())

()()()
```

Given n and k, write an algorithm to give the k-th smallest sequence in **lexicographical** order.

For large data set: `1 ≤ n ≤ 100` and `1 ≤ k ≤ 10^18`

Comment: so what's your question?

Comment: @WimOmbelets
 i guess, the algorithm to solve the above question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This problem can be solved by using **dynamic programming**

- Let `dp[n][m]` = number of valid parentheses that can be created if we have `n` open brackets and `m` close brackets.
- Base case:
  `dp[0][a] = 1 (a >=0)`
- Fill in the matrix using the base case:
  `dp[n][m] = dp[n - 1][m] + (n < m ? dp[n][m - 1]:0 );`

Then, we can slowly build the kth parentheses.

- Start with **a = n open brackets** and **b = n close brackets** and the current result is empty

  ```
  while(k is not 0):
       If number dp[a][b] >= k: 
              If (dp[a - 1][b] >= k) is true:
                 * Append an open bracket '(' to the current result
                 * Decrease a 
              Else:
                 //k is the number of previous smaller lexicographical parentheses
                 * Adjust value of k: `k -= dp[a -1][b]`,
                 * Append a close bracket ')' 
                 * Decrease b
       Else k is invalid
  ```

  Notice that open bracket is less than close bracket in lexicographical order, so we always try to add open bracket first.

Comment: what are base cases for filling number of valid parentheses ?

Comment: Thank you for your algorithm. I ran it and it is correct. But the meaning of dp[n][m] (the number of valid parentheses can be created if we have n -number of open brackets and m - number of close brackets) is confusing to me. How can we get valid parentheses if n != m? I'm not quite understand the meaning of dp[n][m].

Comment: @Danny you can understand that after put down some open brackets and some close brackets, so from those brackets left, how many different valid configurations you can create from those brackets. That's why the base case is dp[0][a], which means when you only have close brackets, so the only thing you can do is put them all down.

Comment: @Danny, be careful for number overflow when building `dp` table, in my implementation, I have to use `BigInteger`! There is also trick to still use long, I believe (but I did not have time to test)

Comment: @PhamTrung I don't understand why we take the base case as equal to 1. Having only open/closed parentheses is a valid sequence? We cannot get to the empty string with just open/closed ones right?

Comment: @user2761431 Assume with n = 4 and we have already created smt like this "(()((" , so with this, the only thing we can do is filled in the 3  closed brackets, which make the base case dp[0][3] = 1 :)

Answer (score 0):

Let `S= any valid sequence of parentheses from n( and n)` . 
Now any valid sequence S can be written as `S=X+Y` where

- `X=valid prefix` i.e. if traversing X from left to right , at any point of time, `numberof'(' >= numberof')'`
- `Y=valid suffix` i.e. if traversing Y from right to left, at any point of time, `numberof'(' <= numberof')'`

For any `S` many pairs of `X` and `Y` are possible.

For our example: `()(())`

```
`()(())` =`empty_string + ()(())` 
         = `( + )(())`
         = `() + (())` 
         = `()( + ())` 
         = `()(( + ))` 
         = `()(() + )`
         = `()(()) + empty_string`
```

**Note that when `X=empty_string`, then number of valid `S` from n`(` and n`)`= number of valid suffix `Y` from n`(` and n`)`**

Now, Algorithm goes like this: 
We will start with `X= empty_string` and recursively grow `X` until `X=S`. At any point of time we have two options to grow `X`, either append '(' or append ')'

Let `dp[a][b]= number of valid suffixes using a '(' and b ')' given X`

`nop=num_open_parenthesis_left`  `ncp=num_closed_parenthesis_left`

```
`calculate(nop,ncp)
{
  if dp[nop][ncp] is not known
  {
    i1=calculate(nop-1,ncp); // Case 1: X= X + "("
    i2=((nop<ncp)?calculate(nop,ncp-1):0);
/*Case 2: X=X+ ")" if nop>=ncp, then after exhausting 1 ')' nop>ncp, therefore there can be no valid suffix*/
    dp[nop][ncp]=i1+i2;
  }
   return dp[nop][ncp];
}`
```

Lets take example,n=3 i.e. 3 `(` and 3 `)`
Now at the very start `X=empty_string`, therefore

`dp[3][3]`= number of valid sequence `S` using 3`(` and 3 `)`
 = number of valid suffixes `Y` from 3 `(` and 3 `)`